# Using pathname as a key in an associative array does not work when array is declared inside of a different function

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

Long time listener, first time caller here:
So, let's say, for whatever reason, I really want to use the names of files as my keys in an associative array, for example, /dev/sda.  For some unholy reason, if I declare the array inside a separate function, for example, an init function,

```
somefunction() { declare -A driveArray; }
somefunction
```

and then later, in another function (or even outside a function), it abjectly fails when I attempt to file something away as a key referenced by a string that happens to also correspond to a path

```
drv="/dev/sda"               # or ${"/dev/sda"} or without quotes.  
driveArray[$drv]=$(readSMART $drv)

# or if I do it like this
for _isd3 in "${!_tmpsmarts[@]}"; do 
    local _sfile="${_tmpsmarts[$_isd3]}";
    driveARRAY[${_isd3}]=$(< $_sfile); 
    rm $_sfile; 
done;
```

Frankly, if I do it in any way that references a path, I get the always fun:

```
./testbed.sh: line 177: /dev/sda: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/dev/sda")
```

Meanwhile, cut and paste the declaration outside of a function and, boom, works just fine.

Well, that just cost me a solid 3 hours. At this point in the project, it would have been easier to learn python from scratch and have used that.  What, pray tell, WHAT is the possible difference here??
Also, just to save everyone the time, it is not lost on me that ye olde '  ' would work here, but I need to pass things around by reference, or, at least, I WANT to, so, that's where we are with that.

Comment: Thanks so much for that little piece of knowledge;  REALLY important to know that if working with arrays and SUPER weird that this fact seems to never come up on any of the top bash blogs (as far as google is concerned) when discussing creating and using arrays.  Like, SUPER weird.  No mention of it being a local variable, no mention of how to declare it as global.  Am I crazy for finding that a little odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare` in a function acts like `local`; the variable only exists in the scope of the function. The `-g` option makes it a global definition instead.

```bash
somefunction() { declare -gA driveArray; }
```